# How to count the number of words in wysiwyg editor javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, bootstrap-wysiwyg

I am using WYSIWYG editor, written there and saved it.

I just want to count the number of characters I have written.

Suppose I have written `"My Count is 4"`, Then it should show me the count as 13

and after marking it bold or Italic the count should remain same as 13.

The code I am using to count is `jQuery(selector).text().length;`

But its returning me the data, along with html tags.

and if I have written **`"My Count is 4"`** in Bold in editor. The count is increasing, because its counting the html `<b></b>` tags also.

Please help me to find the solution.

Comment: kindly please post the fiddle it will be helpful 
you can check using console.log()

Comment: Can include `html`, `js` at Question ?

Comment: Without seeing your code, I'd guess that you have incorrect html causing this. Post your code, or better yet, make a fiddle as suggested already.

Comment: If editor allows markdown syntax as shown this won't be trivial to sort out in a simple answer. If the feature is important suggest you look for an editor that supports it already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
// firstly we'll strip the html out
var myCode = jQuery('#getMe').html();
// strip out tags and line breaks
var cleanCode = myCode.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '').replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"").replace('&nbsp;','');

// then count as normal
var numChars = cleanCode.trim().length;
```

[Have a look at this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/85umbnbc/)

Comment: Thanks Darren, I want something like this, but sadly this is throwing some exception.

`// firstly we'll strip the html out
var myCode = jQuery(selector).text();
var cleanCode = jQuery(myCode).text().replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');

// then count as normal
var numChars = jQuery(cleanCode).text().length;`

Comment: I have tried the updated code, its removing the tags <></> but not removing the tagname, Suppose 

`processed (<strong>damn</strong>) is returning strongdamnstrong, Its also not removing &nbsp, or &lt`.... :(

Comment: Please include the case for spaces at the end. &nbsp;.?

Comment: The Code is working for me :) Thanks @darren...

It will be very helpful for me, if you can include a case for space at the end, because at the end its getting converted to `&nbsp;` and increasing the count.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99690/discussion-between-abhii-and-darren-sweeney).